# In which condition the Test-match declared TIE?

Tags: rules, cricket

When can a test-Match results in **tie** (not-draw)?

What are the factors affecting to such result to be declared?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A test match can only be declared as a tie when the innings second
>   batting team bowled out(losing all the wickets or no batsmen available
>   to bat due to injury) for the second time, with scores level.
>   - [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tied_Test)

If the second batting captain declares the innings after the score gets level, then the match will get tie. But,this will not happen forever in an international cricket match.

All the other factors will affect the result to be declared as tie.

In the history of cricket, only two test matches got tied.

1. One was between [Australia and West Indies](http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/current/match/62888.html).
2. And the other was between [Australia and India](http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/current/match/63438.html).